# Match that doesn't end with a slash

Tags: regex

I'd like to match URLs that don't end in `/`, to use it in Dreamweaver's find tool.

What regex could I use?

For example, I'd like the following URL to be matched:

```
<a href="http://www.sometext"
```

Comment: did you mean parsing links?

Comment: I use Dreamweaver and I can use Find with regular expression. Dreamweaver can find in all the code of one document or all documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this simple regex:

```
href=".+?[^/]"
```

Explanation:

It will match `href="________X"`, where `X != /`.

The following will match:

```
<a href="http://some-url.com">
<a href="http://www.another-url-here.com/content">
```

These ones won't:

```
<a href="http://www.url.com/">
<a href="http://www.url-2.com/posts/2014/">
```

**Edit:**

The following will allow URLs like `<a href=  http://www.url.com>` too.

```
`href=\s*".+?[^/]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use `[^/]"` at the end of your link expression to match any non-slash followed by a close-quote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this

```
href\s*=\s*"[^"]*[^"/\s]\s*"
```